# How do I optimize this recursive function that counts the number of n-digit hexadecimal numbers whose digits equal a sum?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

```
def hexify(summ, l, count = 0):
    if sum == 0:
        return 1
    for i in range(16):
        if i < summ and l > 1:
            count += hexify(summ-i, l-1)
        elif i == summ and l > 0:
            count += 1
    return count 
            
hexa = str(input())[2:] #input tag eg. 0x0121
summ = sum(int(digit, 16) for digit in hexa)
print(hexify(summ, len(hexa)) - 1)
```

What this code does is find the number of n-digit hexadecimal numbers whose digits equal to a certain sum. For example, if the given hexadecimal number is 0x12, the function would return 3 (meaning there are 3 hex numbers whose digits sum to three, excluding 0x12, which are 0x03 0x30 and 0x21).

The problem is the given constraints are 1 > 1 > 10, and the code stops functioning once the length l exceeds 6. How do I optimize this? (Recursion is required)

Comment: This looks like a classic situation where dynamic programming would be great.

Comment: The constraint 1 > 1 is really hard to fulfill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to speed up your code you can use the cache decorator

> @functools.cache(user_function)
> Simple lightweight unbounded function cache. Sometimes called “memoize”.
>
> Returns the same as lru_cache(maxsize=None), creating a thin wrapper
> around a dictionary lookup for the function arguments. Because it
> never needs to evict old values, this is smaller and faster than
> lru_cache() with a size limit.

https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property

```
from functools import cache

@cache
def hexify(summ, l, count = 0):
    if sum == 0:
        return 1
    for i in range(16):
        if i < summ and l > 1:
            count += hexify(summ-i, l-1)
        elif i == summ and l > 0:
            count += 1
    return count 
            
hexa = str(input())[2:] #input tag eg. 0x0121
summ = sum(int(digit, 16) for digit in hexa)
print(hexify(summ, len(hexa)) - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Normally inputting 0xFFFFFFF would cause the program to run for over 10 seconds and eventually cause a runtime error. This somehow cut it down to 0.01s.

Comment: This code is suspicious. (1) You have a function argument called `summ` but the function begins with `if sum == 0:`. Presumably it's a typo and you meant `if summ == 0:`. (2) You have a parameter with a default value, `count`, but that argument is never used. You could simply remove the third argument and add `count = 0` in the first line of the function. It would also be reassuring: when you use `functools.cache`, you need to be careful with the function arguments.